# Download a file from gin framework as multipart formdata

Tags: go

I'm using gin framework context.File(filePath) to send a file but the content type is `application/octet-stream` how can I send it as a `multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: This example may help you https://gist.github.com/schollz/f25d77afc9130b72390748bdbce0d9a3